# Get user's manager without admin consent

Tags: microsoft-graph-api

Using the [MSGraph API](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/overview) is there any way to get a user's manager (or direct reports) without needing a permission that requires admin consent?

There are a few ways to do it but they all require permissions like `User.Read.All` or `Directory.Read.All` which require admin consent. It seems weird that you can't get managers without that when I can just look them up in Outlook or Delve easily enough.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There currently isn't a way to list a user's direct reports or get their manager without needing a permission that requires admin consent on MS Graph. From the [permissions reference](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/permissions-reference#user-permissions) Both of the permissions listed above will require admin consent.

Comment: Damn, I guess I will resort to scraping the [Azure Users list](https://portal.azure.com/#blade/Microsoft_AAD_IAM/UsersManagementMenuBlade/MsGraphUsers).

Answer (score 1):

I found a workaround for my specific case, where I want to use the API only for me - I'm not making a product for anyone else. It's a bit of a hack.

Basically go to [the Azure users page](https://portal.azure.com/#blade/Microsoft_AAD_IAM/UsersManagementMenuBlade/MsGraphUsers) and open dev tools. Search for a user or something and you will see requests to https://graph.microsoft.com/beta/$batch.

Check one of those requests and it will have a request header like `Authorization: Bearer <a_long_string>`.

You can use that same header to make graph requests yourself. I'm not exactly sure what permissions it has but it let me get `/beta/users?$expand=manager` which I couldn't otherwise do. Note you can only get something like 100 users per request but the response includes a URL to get the next 100 so it's pretty easy to get them all.

The authorization token does not last long so it is only really useful for one-time export sort of tasks.